# Greedy Algorithm in C

Tags: c, cs50

So I started learning C for 2 days in the course of CS50. In week #2 problem set there was a challenge of coding for the Greedy Algorithms which basically giving back to the customer their change at a minimum amount of coins. 
Here is my solution for it writen in CS50 sandbox.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    //Assign value
    int q = 0; int d = 0; int n = 0; int p =0;
    int left;
    int count = 0;
    float change;

    // Promting user for change.
    do
    {
       change = get_float("Change:");
    }
    while(change < 0);

    // Convert cent to dollar.
    int cent = round(change * 100);
    printf("Dollar %i\n", cent);

    //Counting coin
    while(cent >=25)
    {
        q++;
        left = cent - 25;
    }
    while(left >=10)
    {
        d++;
        left = left -10;
    }
    while(left >=5)
    {
        n++;
        left = left -5;
    }
    while(left >=1)
    {
        p++;
        left=left-1;
    }
    count = q + d + n + p;  
    printf("Total coin: %i\n", count);
}
```

I run the code by the CS50 Terminal in the CS50 sandbox and get this error:

```
cash.c:27:10: runtime error: signed integer overflow: 2147483647 + 1 cannot be represented in type 'int'
```

I understand that my loop goes over the limitation of storing data in int. But I cannot find a way to fix it.

Comment: The first `while` loop uses `cent` instead of `left`, but `cent` isn't being decreased. You should just use `cent` everywhere, and remove `left`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don´t need to change the type of `q` which is `int` - for which this error message comes up at all.

The problem is somewhere else:

`q` goes beyond the bounds of the capable values to be hold in an `int` because in the loop:

```
while(cent >=25)
{ 
    q++;
    left = cent - 25;
}
```

the value to proof the condition, `cent`, never gets decremented and so the loop never terminates. You only assign `cent - 25` to `left`, `cent` itself is unchanged.

You don´t need the `left` variable by the way.

Rather use:

```
//Counting coin
while(cent >= 25)
{
    q++;
    cent = cent - 25;
}
while(cent >= 10)
{
    d++;
    cent = cent - 10;
}
while(cent >= 5)
{
    n++;
    cent = cent - 5;
}
while(cent >= 1)
{
    p++;
    cent = cent - 1;
}
```

Furthermore:

```
printf("Dollar %i\n", cent);
```

is not correct since you try to print the money to change in Cent, not Dollar:

```
printf("Change in Cent: %i\n", cent);
```

---

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    //Assign value
    int q = 0; int d = 0; int n = 0; int p = 0;
    int count = 0;
    float change;

    // Promting user for change.
    do
    {
       change = get_float("Change in Dollar:");
    }
    while(change < 0);

    // Convert cent to dollar.
    int cent = round(change * 100);
    printf("Change in Cent: %i\n", cent);

    //Counting coin
    while(cent >= 25)
    {
        q++;
        cent = cent - 25;
    }
    while(cent >= 10)
    {
        d++;
        cent = cent - 10;
    }
    while(cent >= 5)
    {
        n++;
        cent = cent - 5;
    }
    while(cent >= 1)
    {
        p++;
        cent = cent - 1;
    }

    count = q + d + n + p;  
    printf("Total amount of coins: %i\n", count);
}
```

Comment: You mean I should press the green check button on your answer ?
I'm sorry I don't know that I can only click on 1 answer.  All the answers are extremely helpful. And I appreciate all of them, so I thought I could click the green check on every answer.
Sorry for my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
while(cent >=25) 
    q++;
    left = cent - 25;
}
```

If `cent` is originally 25 of greater, will this loop ever end? `cent` never changes, so no. The other loops are fine, so all you have to do is use the same pattern you used for the other loops for this one too.

Comment: So, here you got your up-vote first and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61135333/greedy-algorithm-in-c/61135652?noredirect=1#comment108169410_61135652) as apoligy.